# Integrating Skype, speech recognition and MS Access

Tags: speech-recognition, voip, voice-recognition, speech, speech-to-text

I need to achieve the following,  in order to avoid having to develop a very costly web app.  Please advise if it is feasible to use  Skype (or another PDA friendly VOIP) to call a computer that is  running an MS Access form. The MS Access form would be integrated with speech-recognition  and text-to-speech, to communicate back and forth via Skype VOIP.  The remote Skype user would use voice commands to run MS Access macros. Some of these macros would use text-to-speech to prompt the user to verbally input data into the MS Access form fields.  I have already tested  the apps "Windows 7’s Speech Recognition" and "Dragon Naturally Speaking", but they don’t work with VOIP, because they require the speech to be inputted from a microphone and can not work if the speech is inputted from the speaker,  so the speech-recognition needs to be running on the computer that is running the MS Access app and should not be running  on the user’s side.  I am hoping that such a setup can be achieved  using another app or with some custom programming. Please outline the proper procedure and/or provide insight.

Thank you very much in advance, Nathaniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some points just to clarify a few things from your question.

Microsoft Speech Recognition is not limited to microphone input. You can capture audio to a wav file and then process the captured audio.  See SpeechRecognitionEngine.SetInputToWaveFile - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.setinputtowavefile.aspx. Note that this requires the use of an inproc recognizer (SpeechRecognitionEngine) instead of the shared recognizer (SpeechRecognizer). This means you must have your own speech recognition application, this method does not use the Windows desktop speech recognition to control applications.

Many IVR systems accept VOIP input using standards like SIP. The Microsoft Speech Server product that got consumed by Microsoft Lync supports VOIP input. See SIP Peers -  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lync/bb812717(v=office.12).aspx. However, I believe Skype does not use VOIP standards like SIP without extra costs - http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/business/skype-connect/

When you are trying to voice enable your access application, are you using standard voice control for access like http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/speech-recognition-commands-in-access-HA001034591.aspx ?

Comment: Michael is correct that Skype uses there own proprietary VOIP protocol that will not work with SIP. The hosted version of Voxeo Prophecy does support Skype and when you create an application on their service it automatically provide you with a Skype number to call it with.

Answer (score 0):

I have integrated MS Access applications and databases with [IVR systems](http://www.voxeo.com/library/ivr.jsp). If you want speech recognition over a telephone you need an IVR platform that supports speech recogntion not a desktop speech recognition system, as you have already determined. I would go with an IVR platform that supports the web based open standard called [VoiceXML](http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml20/).

Since MS Access is a Microsoft technology I would use .NET to develop the VoiceXML application and the [integration to MS Access](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317114).  A useful tool for developing VoiceXML with ASP.NET MVC is [VoiceModel](http://voicemodel.codeplex.com/). It is an open source project that makes it easier to develop VoiceXML applications in .NET.  There are a number of samples in the project. Take a look at the [WeatherVoice example](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2012/01/using-google-weather-api-in-voicexml.html) which demonstrates how to integrate with a back-end system.

A good IVR platform that you can try out for free is [Voxeo Prophecy](http://www.voxeo.com/products/voicexml-ivr-platform.jsp). The free version comes with speech recognition and it will scale to very large applications. The native telephony interface is SIP, so that should work with your VOIP requirement. It is easy to use and install.  There is also a hosted version you can use for free and only pay when you go into production.